# Insert link in a social media icon

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, icons

I've made a social media icon list for my webpage but I don't know how to insert a link in them so they take you somewhere when clicking... I've tried using the "a" tag but it's not working:

```
<div class="leftside">
    <ul class="socialmediaicons">
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/EnUnChasquido"></a><i class="fa 
fa-facebook"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I've only tried on the facebook icon and it doesn't work, what am doing wrong?

Comment: It works now but it doesn't look very good, the "Facebook" I wrote appears on the icon now, just on top of the logo and I have to click specifically there to make it work, is there a way to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Its working now

```html
<div class="leftside">
  <ul class="socialmediaicons">
    <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/EnUnChasquido" rel="http://www.facebook.com/">Facebook<i class="fa 
fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use like this

```
<div class="leftside">
            <ul class="socialmediaicons">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/EnUnChasquido"><li><i class="fa 
        fa-facebook"></i></li></a>
              <li><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the entire i tag within the anchor tag

Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/VrtuosArs/14x0rbtb/

Hope the following code snippet solves your problem

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="leftside">
  <ul class="socialmediaicons">
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/EnUnChasquido" target="_blank"><i class="fa 
fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The anchor element tag is the letter “a” surrounded by angle brackets like this:  . Both the opening and closing attributes are required, and all of the content between the tags makes up the anchor source. If we want to use just a single word as an anchor, we wrap just that one word in anchor tags. we can use text, image, icons as content